# Не запускается порт localhost React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Пытаюсь запустить приложение, по видео из ютуба, но у меня отсутствует строчка на каком порту запускается приложение. Пытаюсь перейти на localhost 19002, но выдаёт ошибку
[[image: 1]

Comment: А почему порт на 2 больше?

Comment: Ну как я  понял порт всегда такой должен быть

Comment: А что происходит при сканировании QR кода?